# Print multiple values in Array list Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Given java code:

```
private List<String> list_from = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> list_dest = new ArrayList<String>();
```

values of `list_from` is:

```
[v5, v3, v5, v1, v1, v6, v6, v3, v4, v5, v4, v6]
```

values of `list_dest` is:

```
[v3, v5, v1, v5, v6, v1, v3, v6, v5, v4, v6, v4]
```

I'm using loop for to print out the values in list_from with an if statement:

```
for(int i=0;i < list_from.size();i++){                    
    if(list_dest.get(i+1) == list_from.get(i)){
        System.out.println(list_from.get(i));
    }
}
```

it gives out a correct result but with unknown error at an if statement.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 18, Size: 18
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Can you provide content of this error?

Comment: *with unknown error at an if statement.* It's never an unknown error... Post the stack trace

Comment: `i` will go until `list_from.size()`, so `list_dest.get(i+1)` looks suspicious. For example, if the two lists have the same size, then you'll get an index out of bounds exception

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: _it gives out a correct result_, surely this cannot give correct output --> `if(list_dest.get(i+1) == list_from.get(i))` , you're comparing Strings with `==`.

Comment: @MichałPiątkowski edited

Comment: Please don't use the "back" button of your browser to edit your question. It breaks the edits made by others. Instead use the [edit] link below your question or the one I provided here

Comment: @Frakcool so sorry. I'm just a newbie. I will mention about this next time

Comment: Please don't edit the solution inside your question. [Accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) one of the ones given below instead. Or answer your own question with the solution you got (But if it's going to be equal to one or more like the ones below, then just accept it)

Comment: I know you're new to the site, so I recommend you to take the [tour], and learn [ask], this will improve your questions greatly and won't get downvoted. Next time do a [Google search](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=arrayindexoutofboundsexception+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=5QUWWb7oMe_P8AfAqoeYCA) before asking too,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing strings should be done by `string.equals(string2)`.
Strings are objects. You should always use `equals` when comparing objects.
Also you are comparing too many indexes in array.

Your code should look like that:

```
for(int i=0;i < list_from.size()-1;i++){                    
    if(list_dest.get(i).equals(list_from.get(i+1))){
        System.out.println(list_from.get(i));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

list_dest.get(i+1), here's the problem.
In the last iteration, value of i is the maximum index that is possible. When you add 1 to it it will give arrayOutOfBoundsException.

Also better to use string.equals() method to compare string.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Problems. First, change the loop condition to `<list_from.size()-1`.

Second, compare Strings with `.equals()`, and not `==`.

Code becomes

```
for(int i=0;i < list_from.size()-1;i++){                    
    if(list_dest.get(i+1).equals(list_from.get(i))){
        System.out.println(list_from.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much! coz the code has so many stuff I have to handle. Didn't mention about it. Got it working now :)